# TypeError when using a method from a class - python

Tags: python, k-means

I have an improved kmeans algorithm (KPlusPlus) that builds on the class kmeans. Detk is another class inherited from KPlusPlus.

The objective of the KPlusPlus class is to find out the optimal seeding for finding the kmeans centroids ([Source](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/improved-seeding-for-clustering-with-k-means/))

Detk calculates the gap statistic to find the optimal number of clusters. I have found this code from  [here](https://datasciencelab.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/selection-of-k-in-k-means-clustering-reloaded/)

```
# kmeans class 
class KMeans():
def __init__(self, K, X=None, N=0):
    self.K = K
    if X == None:
        if N == 0:
            raise Exception("If no data is provided, \
                             a parameter N (number of points) is needed")
        else:
            self.N = N
            self.X = self._init_board_gauss(N, K)
    else:
        self.X = X
        self.N = len(X)
    self.mu = None
    self.clusters = None
    self.method = None

def _init_board_gauss(self, N, k):
    n = float(N)/k
    X = []
    for i in range(k):
        c = (random.uniform(-1,1), random.uniform(-1,1))
        s = random.uniform(0.05,0.15)
        x = []
        while len(x) < n:
            a,b = np.array([np.random.normal(c[0],s),np.random.normal(c[1],s)])
            # Continue drawing points from the distribution in the range [-1,1]
            if abs(a) and abs(b)<1:
                x.append([a,b])
        X.extend(x)
    X = np.array(X)[:N]
    return X

def plot_board(self):
    X = self.X
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.xlim(-1,1)
    plt.ylim(-1,1)
    if self.mu and self.clusters:
        mu = self.mu
        clus = self.clusters
        K = self.K
        for m, clu in clus.items():
            cs = cm.spectral(1.*m/self.K)
            plt.plot(mu[m][0], mu[m][1], 'o', marker='*', \
                     markersize=12, color=cs)
            plt.plot(zip(*clus[m])[0], zip(*clus[m])[1], '.', \
                     markersize=8, color=cs, alpha=0.5)
    else:
        plt.plot(zip(*X)[0], zip(*X)[1], '.', alpha=0.5)
    if self.method == '++':
        tit = 'K-means++'
    else:
        tit = 'K-means with random initialization'
    pars = 'N=%s, K=%s' % (str(self.N), str(self.K))
    plt.title('\n'.join([pars, tit]), fontsize=16)
    plt.savefig('kpp_N%s_K%s.png' % (str(self.N), str(self.K)), \
                bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)

def _cluster_points(self):
    mu = self.mu
    clusters  = {}
    for x in self.X:
        bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                         for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
        try:
            clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
        except KeyError:
            clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
    self.clusters = clusters

def _reevaluate_centers(self):
    clusters = self.clusters
    newmu = []
    keys = sorted(self.clusters.keys())
    for k in keys:
        newmu.append(np.mean(clusters[k], axis = 0))
    self.mu = newmu

def _has_converged(self):
    K = len(self.oldmu)
    return(set([tuple(a) for a in self.mu]) == \
           set([tuple(a) for a in self.oldmu])\
           and len(set([tuple(a) for a in self.mu])) == K)

def find_centers(self,K, method='random'):
    self.method = method
    X = self.X
    K = self.K
    self.oldmu = random.sample(X, K)
    if method != '++':
        # Initialize to K random centers
        self.mu = random.sample(X, K)
    while not self._has_converged():
        self.oldmu = self.mu
        # Assign all points in X to clusters
        self._cluster_points()
        # Reevaluate centers
        self._reevaluate_centers()
```

The KPlusPlus class inherits from kmeans to find the optimal seeding

```
class KPlusPlus(KMeans):
def _dist_from_centers(self):
    cent = self.mu
    X = self.X
    D2 = np.array([min([np.linalg.norm(x-c)**2 for c in cent]) for x in X])
    self.D2 = D2

def _choose_next_center(self):
    self.probs = self.D2/self.D2.sum()
    self.cumprobs = self.probs.cumsum()
    r = random.random()
    ind = np.where(self.cumprobs >= r)[0][0]
    return(self.X[ind])

def init_centers(self,K):
    self.K = K
    self.mu = random.sample(self.X, 1)
    while len(self.mu) < self.K:
        self._dist_from_centers()
        self.mu.append(self._choose_next_center())

def plot_init_centers(self):
    X = self.X
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.xlim(-1,1)
    plt.ylim(-1,1)
    plt.plot(zip(*X)[0], zip(*X)[1], '.', alpha=0.5)
    plt.plot(zip(*self.mu)[0], zip(*self.mu)[1], 'ro')
    plt.savefig('kpp_init_N%s_K%s.png' % (str(self.N),str(self.K)), \
                bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
```

The class Detk inherits from KPlusPlus to find the optmal number of clusters based on gap statistic

```
class DetK(KPlusPlus):
def fK(self, thisk, Skm1=0):
    X = self.X
    Nd = len(X[0])
    a = lambda k, Nd: 1 - 3/(4*Nd) if k == 2 else a(k-1, Nd) + (1-a(k-1, Nd))/6
    self.find_centers(thisk, method='++')
    mu, clusters = self.mu, self.clusters
    Sk = sum([np.linalg.norm(mu[i]-c)**2 \
             for i in range(thisk) for c in clusters[i]])
    if thisk == 1:
        fs = 1
    elif Skm1 == 0:
        fs = 1
    else:
        fs = Sk/(a(thisk,Nd)*Skm1)
    return fs, Sk  

def _bounding_box(self):
    X = self.X
    xmin, xmax = min(X,key=lambda a:a[0])[0], max(X,key=lambda a:a[0])[0]
    ymin, ymax = min(X,key=lambda a:a[1])[1], max(X,key=lambda a:a[1])[1]
    return (xmin,xmax), (ymin,ymax)        

def gap(self, thisk):
    X = self.X
    (xmin,xmax), (ymin,ymax) = self._bounding_box()
    self.init_centers(thisk)
    self.find_centers(thisk, method='++')
    mu, clusters = self.mu, self.clusters
    Wk = np.log(sum([np.linalg.norm(mu[i]-c)**2/(2*len(c)) \
                for i in range(thisk) for c in clusters[i]]))
    # Create B reference datasets
    B = 10
    BWkbs = zeros(B)
    for i in range(B):
        Xb = []
        for n in range(len(X)):
            Xb.append([random.uniform(xmin,xmax), \
                      random.uniform(ymin,ymax)])
        Xb = np.array(Xb)
        kb = DetK(thisk, X=Xb)
        kb.init_centers(thisk)
        kb.find_centers(thisk, method='++')
        ms, cs = kb.mu, kb.clusters
        BWkbs[i] = np.log(sum([np.linalg.norm(ms[j]-c)**2/(2*len(c)) \
                          for j in range(thisk) for c in cs[j]]))
    Wkb = sum(BWkbs)/B
    sk = np.sqrt(sum((BWkbs-Wkb)**2)/float(B))*np.sqrt(1+1/B)
    return Wk, Wkb, sk

def run(self, maxk, which='both'):
    ks = range(1,maxk)
    fs = zeros(len(ks))
    Wks,Wkbs,sks = zeros(len(ks)+1),zeros(len(ks)+1),zeros(len(ks)+1)
    # Special case K=1
    self.init_centers(1)
    if which == 'f':
        fs[0], Sk = self.fK(1)
    elif which == 'gap':
        Wks[0], Wkbs[0], sks[0] = self.gap(1)
    else:
        fs[0], Sk = self.fK(1)
        Wks[0], Wkbs[0], sks[0] = self.gap(1)
    # Rest of Ks
    for k in ks[1:]:
        self.init_centers(k)
        if which == 'f':
            fs[k-1], Sk = self.fK(k, Skm1=Sk)
        elif which == 'gap':
            Wks[k-1], Wkbs[k-1], sks[k-1] = self.gap(k)
        else:
            fs[k-1], Sk = self.fK(k, Skm1=Sk)
            Wks[k-1], Wkbs[k-1], sks[k-1] = self.gap(k)
    if which == 'f':
        self.fs = fs
    elif which == 'gap':
        G = []
        for i in range(len(ks)):
            G.append((Wkbs-Wks)[i] - ((Wkbs-Wks)[i+1]-sks[i+1]))
        self.G = np.array(G)
    else:
        self.fs = fs
        G = []
        for i in range(len(ks)):
            G.append((Wkbs-Wks)[i] - ((Wkbs-Wks)[i+1]-sks[i+1]))
        self.G = np.array(G)
```

When I try to run the following program on a given number of points (`locArray`)

```
locArray = np.array(locArrayMaster[counter])

kmeanscluster = DetK(2, X = locArray)
kmeanscluster.run(5)
noClusters[counter] = np.where(kmeanscluster.fs == min(kmeanscluster.fs))[0][0]+ 1
```

it returns me the following error

```
File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "C:/Users/Documents/SUMOTraffic/kplusplus.py", line 355, in <module>
kmeanscluster.run(5)

File "C:/Users/Documents/SUMOTraffic/kplusplus.py", line 217, in run
Wks[0], Wkbs[0], sks[0] = self.gap(1)

File "C:/Users/Documents/SUMOTraffic/kplusplus.py", line 200, in gap
for j in range(thisk) for c in cs[j]]))

TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: put a line: `print(type(cs))` after the line `ms, cs = kb.mu, kb.clusters` in gap. This will tell you why `cs[j]` is failing

Comment: `<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'dict'>
<type 'NoneType'>`

Comment: `kb.clusters` returns `None` in the last iteration. What is kb.clusters supposed to mean?

Comment: kb.clusters is a dict with cluster id's as keys and clusterpoints as values.

Comment: I checked the number of clusters when it gave me the error. looks like the gap class returns only one cluster.

Comment: I'm not sure that's your problem... the error is generated before `gap()` returns.. I think it may be related to `self.X` in the `_cluster_points` method. Try putting `len(self.X)` somewhere in the for loop of `gap()`

Comment: If `self.X` were to be a list of zero length there, it would generate no error, and leave `self.clusters` as a None object as it was initialized

Comment: What do you mean putting `len(self.X)`? to check if the length is greater than zero?

Comment: `print(len(self.X))`... I'm a binary chop kind of debugger ;)

Comment: `<type 'dict'>
798
<type 'dict'>
797
<type 'dict'>
797
<type 'NoneType'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the failure of the kmeans algorithm to find the cluster centres when the number of clusters is just 1. Hence the cluster dictionary is not created for this case. So, added an extra line of code in the class `DetK` which checks if the type of cluster dictionary is `'NoneType'` and if it returns `TRUE`, recalculates the cluster centres again.

```
class DetK(KPlusPlus):
    def fK(self, thisk, Skm1=0):
        X = self.X
        Nd = len(X[0])
        a = lambda k, Nd: 1 - 3/(4*Nd) if k == 2 else a(k-1, Nd) + (1-a(k-1, Nd))/6
        self.find_centers(thisk, method='++')
```

> ```
>         while type(self.clusters) is not dict:
>             self.find_centers(thisk, method = '++')
> ```

```
        mu, clusters = self.mu, self.clusters
        Sk = sum([np.linalg.norm(mu[i]-c)**2 \
                 for i in range(thisk) for c in clusters[i]])
        if thisk == 1:
            fs = 1
        elif Skm1 == 0:
            fs = 1
        else:
            fs = Sk/(a(thisk,Nd)*Skm1)
        return fs, Sk
```